# SSLHandshakeException - java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: non-null policy tree required and policy tree is null

Tags: java, security, ssl, sslhandshakeexception

I have the server root cert in my truststore and I after setting -Djavax.net.debug=all, I can see that the truststore is initialized and the trusted cert is there:

```
trustStore is: test.truststore
trustStore type is : jks
trustStore provider is : 
init truststore
adding as trusted cert:
Subject: CN=Test Root, OU=test, O=test, C=us
Issuer:  CN=Test Root, OU=test, O=test, C=us
Algorithm: RSA; Serial number: 0x1
Valid from Thu Sep 05 14:49:45 GMT+00:00 2013 until Sun Sep 05 14:49:45 GMT+00:00 2021
```

Next I can see in the server certificate chain, the trusted cert:

```
chain [2] = [
[
  Version: V3
  Subject: CN=Test Root, OU=test, O=test, C=us
  Signature Algorithm: SHA1withRSA, OID = 1.2.840.113549.1.1.5

  Key:  Sun RSA public key, 2048 bits
  modulus: 259491476017...{etc}
  public exponent: 65537
  Validity: [From: Thu Sep 05 14:49:45 GMT+00:00 2013,
               To: Sun Sep 05 14:49:45 GMT+00:00 2021]
  Issuer: CN=Test Root, OU=test, O=test, C=us
  SerialNumber: [    01]
```

But for some reason, the handshake still fails:

```
%% Invalidated:  [Session-1, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA]
Thread-2, SEND TLSv1 ALERT:  fatal, description = certificate_unknown
Thread-2, WRITE: TLSv1 Alert, length = 2
[Raw write]: length = 7
0000: 15 03 01 00 02 02 2E                               .......
Thread-2, called closeSocket()
Thread-2, handling exception: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException:         sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path validation failed: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: non-null policy tree required and policy tree is null
Thread-2, IOException in getSession():  javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException:   sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path validation failed:   java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: non-null policy tree required and policy tree is null
```

What does that "non-null policy tree required and policy tree is null" mean?

Comment: It will be difficult to answer your question without a working code sample. Please post your code as an [minimal example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates your problem.

Answer (score 2):

I saw this issue when an application tried to verify a chain that has `Require Explicit Policy:0` (as DoD Intermediates do) and included the self-signed cert both in the certPath  and the PKIXParameters as trust anchor. Similar to:

```
CertPath certPath = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509").generateCertPath(chain);
X509Certificate ca = (X509Certificate)chain.get(chain.size() - 1);
TrustAnchor trustAnchor = new TrustAnchor((X509Certificate)ca, null);
PKIXParameters params = new PKIXParameters(Collections.singleton(trustAnchor));
```

I have not tried this with an SSLSocket but I assume you may see it if the server sends the root (they really shouldn't). I think a valid fix would be to see if the final cert isSelfIssued (`getSubjectX500Principal() equals getIssuerX500Principal()`) and remove it from the chain before calling a validator on it. Similar to:

```
if (ca.getSubjectX500Principal().equals(ca.getIssuerX500Principal())) {
  chain.remove(ca);
}
```

Untested with SSL but it's what worked for me when validating a private key + full chain read in from PEM file.

BouncyCastle stack trace compared to the sun provider:

```
java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: non-null policy tree required and policy tree is null
        at sun.security.provider.certpath.PKIXMasterCertPathValidator.validate(PKIXMasterCertPathValidator.java:135)
        at sun.security.provider.certpath.PKIXCertPathValidator.validate(PKIXCertPathValidator.java:233)
        at sun.security.provider.certpath.PKIXCertPathValidator.validate(PKIXCertPathValidator.java:141)
        at sun.security.provider.certpath.PKIXCertPathValidator.engineValidate(PKIXCertPathValidator.java:80)
        at java.security.cert.CertPathValidator.validate(CertPathValidator.java:292)
        at test.main(test.java:52)
Caused by: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: non-null policy tree required and policy tree is null
        at sun.security.provider.certpath.PolicyChecker.processPolicies(PolicyChecker.java:572)
        at sun.security.provider.certpath.PolicyChecker.checkPolicy(PolicyChecker.java:225)
        at sun.security.provider.certpath.PolicyChecker.check(PolicyChecker.java:180)
        at sun.security.provider.certpath.PKIXMasterCertPathValidator.validate(PKIXMasterCertPathValidator.java:125)
        ... 5 more
```

```
org.bouncycastle.jce.exception.ExtCertPathValidatorException: No valid policy tree found when one expected.
        at org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.RFC3280CertPathUtilities.processCertF(Unknown Source)
        at org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.PKIXCertPathValidatorSpi.engineValidate(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.cert.CertPathValidator.validate(CertPathValidator.java:292)
        at test.main(test.java:53)
```

Comment: That is in fact a valid solution, because the root usually has no policies but must be considered to allow any policy. However, the validator does not expect that the root certificate is in the chain. (Which is a bug, because it is unusual yet not forbidden to include it.) Also see [this useful answer](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/24929/134095).